# Determining values for Default Correlation between two companies

Tags: r, statistical-significance, correlation, finance, risk

I'm a second year undergrad university statistics student working on a real life project for IDB, a bank in Latin America. However the project is really above my level, and I could do with some help.

As the title suggests, I need to determine the default correlation coefficient value between any two companies in Latin America, but I have researched this for a while and don't know where to get started.

These are the requirements:

- Approach to be based on empirical data.
- The approach should de detailed enough to be replicable by a third party with little supervision.
- Data inputs should be available from publicly available sources.
- Computer code should be produced in an open source programing language (preferably R)
- Final deliverable should include: description of the methodology with detailed steps, data files and program code scripts.
- Final Correlation estimates should possess an acceptable level of statistical significance.

The data I'll be using will be basic stuff such as Return on Equity or Credit Ratings, the sort of data I could find on Yahoo Finance.

The Merton Model looks promising so far, I like the look of using Copulas and other techniques - but they look far too complicated for my expertise. There are many other current models that do this like Credit+ or CreditMetrics, but these are very complicated industry standard.

Any advice would be hugely helpful. I just want a methodology that is robust and not necessarily complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean by default correlation between companies, something like if Ford defaults then Honda is likely to default, too? If so, isn't the [Merton model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merton_model) just a model of default probability based on the firm characteristics, regardless of what happens to other firms?

Comment: That's correct, it means if one company defaults, like Ford, then Honda will default simultaneously ( in a time interval ~ 1 year ). The Merton model can be used to evaluate the assets and equity under control by one company, hence if another company holds the same assets it can predict whether the other company will default. But like you say, the relationship between the two isn't clear and this is what I'm stuck on. Thanks for your help so far.